# How to add multiple rows after each row in pandas that depends on the value of the row?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

What I have currently is a data that looks like this:

| date | hour |
| --- | --- |
| 21/06/2000 | 6 |
| 22/06/2000 | 6 |
| 23/06/2000 | 6 |
| 24/06/2000 | 6 |

What I would like to achieve:

| date | hour |
| --- | --- |
| 21/06/2000 | 6 |
| 21/06/2000 | 10 |
| 21/06/2000 | 14 |
| 21/06/2000 | 18 |
| 22/06/2000 | 6 |
| 22/06/2000 | 10 |
| 22/06/2000 | 14 |
| 22/06/2000 | 18 |
| ... so on and so forth | ... |

I am unable to find any solution for this on the internet where I only found ways to add new EMPTY rows which is not what I aim for. Any solution would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
To recreate the dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd

date = ['21/06/2000', '22/06/2000', '23/06/2000', '24/06/2000']
hour = [6, 6, 6, 6]

df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(date, hour)),
               columns =['date', 'hour'])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to assign a list to the "Hour" column, then `explode` it:

```
df = df.assign(hour=[[df.at[0,'hour'] + 4*i for i in range(4)]]*len(df)).explode('hour').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
          date hour
0   21/06/2000    6
1   21/06/2000   10
2   21/06/2000   14
3   21/06/2000   18
4   22/06/2000    6
5   22/06/2000   10
6   22/06/2000   14
7   22/06/2000   18
8   23/06/2000    6
9   23/06/2000   10
10  23/06/2000   14
11  23/06/2000   18
12  24/06/2000    6
13  24/06/2000   10
14  24/06/2000   14
15  24/06/2000   18
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using [`repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) and [`numpy`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html):

```
import numpy as np
df2 = (df.loc[df.index.repeat(4)]
         .reset_index(drop=True)
       )
df2['hour'] += np.arange(len(df2))%4*4
```

Or maybe even easier using an explicit array of the hours to add and [`numpy.tile`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.tile.html?highlight=tile#numpy.tile):

```
import numpy as np
df2 = (df.loc[df.index.repeat(4)]
         .reset_index(drop=True)
       )
df2['hour'] += np.tile([0,4,8,12], len(df))
```

Output:

```
          date  hour
0   21/06/2000     6
1   21/06/2000    10
2   21/06/2000    14
3   21/06/2000    18
4   22/06/2000     6
5   22/06/2000    10
6   22/06/2000    14
7   22/06/2000    18
8   23/06/2000     6
9   23/06/2000    10
10  23/06/2000    14
11  23/06/2000    18
12  24/06/2000     6
13  24/06/2000    10
14  24/06/2000    14
15  24/06/2000    18
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are assigning `[6,10,14,18]` to each row, you can use the [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) function from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/) to achieve this:

```py
# the dev version has improvements
# pip install git+https://github.com/pyjanitor-devs/pyjanitor.git
import janitor
import pandas as pd

df.complete('date', {'hour':[6,10,14,18]})
          date  hour
0   21/06/2000     6
1   21/06/2000    10
2   21/06/2000    14
3   21/06/2000    18
4   22/06/2000     6
5   22/06/2000    10
6   22/06/2000    14
7   22/06/2000    18
8   23/06/2000     6
9   23/06/2000    10
10  23/06/2000    14
11  23/06/2000    18
12  24/06/2000     6
13  24/06/2000    10
14  24/06/2000    14
15  24/06/2000    18
```